# Is the set of non-differentiable points of a norm, as a real-valued function, closed?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

Assume the function $f: R^n \to R$ is a norm on $R^n$. We know $f$ is Lipschitz continuous on $R^n$. Hence, the set of non-differentiable points of $f$ has zero measure in $R^n$. My question is if the latter set is a closed subset of $R^n$?

Comment: I haven't checked the details, but my guess would be that a norm on $\Bbb{C}$ whose unit disk is the convex hull of the set of points $e^{2\pi i/n}$ ($n = 1, 2, \ldots$) would be a counterexample.

Comment: I should have written $e^{\pm 2\pi i/n}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The set of non-differentiability of $f$ need not be closed.

Here is a counter-example: Let $K$ be the convex hull of the points

$$ X = \bigl\{ \bigl(\pm\cos\tfrac{\pi}{2^n},\pm\sin\tfrac{\pi}{2^n}\bigr) : n = 1, 2, \ldots \bigr\},$$

and let $f$ be the [Minkowski functional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_functional) of $K$. Since $K$ is convex, balanced, and absorbing, $f$ is indeed a norm on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

[image: Set K]

Then the set of non-differentiability $N$ of $f$ is precisely

$$ N = \{ rx : r \geq 0 \text{ and } x \in X \}, $$

which is not closed. (Note that $\overline{N}$ must also include the $x$-axis.)

The following is the graph of the function $\theta \mapsto f((\cos\theta,\sin\theta))$:

[image: graph of the norm]